# How can I use WP_Query argument 'Like %..%'?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, phpmyadmin

I didn't find a good headline but this is my problem:

I have this code (**works fine!**):

```
  $resume_args = array();

  $resume_args['post_type'] = 'resume';
  $resume_args['posts_per_page'] = 7;
  $resume_args['paged'] = $paged;

  $resume_args['order'] = 'DESC';
  $resume_args['orderby'] = 'ID';

   $resume_search_cat = array(
      'key' => '_resume_category',
      'value' => str_replace('-', ' ',$kategorie),
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    );

  /** Enable multiple meta query **/
  $resume_args['meta_query'] = array(
    $resume_search_cat
  );

  $resumes = new WP_Query($resume_args);
```

With this code I get **all** posts of the `post_type` 'resume'.

But now I want all posts of the `post_type` 'resume' *with* a clear post_content.

For example some post_contents:

1. post_content = 'Hello World this is **foo** bar'
2. post_content = 'Hello World this is **foo**bar'
3. post_content = 'Hello stackexchange this**foo**isbar'

In phpmyadmin I use this:

```
"...WHERE post_content LIKE '%foo%'" //output: all three examples
```

## **The question:**

**How can I archive this in/with wordpress WP_Query?**

*I searched a lot with google but can't fine any solution.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another search in Wordpress codex I find the solution:

> Search Parameter Show posts based on a keyword search.
>
> s (string) - Search keyword. Show Posts based on a keyword search
>
> Display posts that match the search term "keyword":
>
> $query = new WP_Query( array( 's' => 'keyword' ) );

http://codex.wordpress.org/wp_query#Search_Parameter

For my example:

```
  $resume_args = array();

  $resume_args['post_type'] = 'resume';
  $resume_args['posts_per_page'] = 7;
  $resume_args['paged'] = $paged;

  $resume_args['order'] = 'DESC';
  $resume_args['orderby'] = 'ID';

  $resume_args['s'] = 'foo';

   $resume_search_cat = array(
      'key' => '_resume_category',
      'value' => str_replace('-', ' ',$kategorie),
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    );

  /** Enable multiple meta query **/
  $resume_args['meta_query'] = array(
    $resume_search_cat
  );

  $resumes = new WP_Query($resume_args);
```